# Changing a single word in an comma-separated multi-line text file in Python without using CSV or mapping

Tags: python

Text file **rf.txt**:

```
user1, task1
user2, task2
user3, task3
```

The intention is to change `user2` to `user4`:

```
user1, task1
user4, task2
user3, task3
```

How is it done without using csv module, mapping or anything beyond the most basic file read/write operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bit dumb but basic:

```
f = open('file', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open('file', 'w')

for l in lines:
    if 'user2' in l:
        l = l.split(', ')
        l[0] = 'user4'
        l = ', '.join(l)
        #print(l)
        f.write(l)
    else:
        f.write(l)

f.close()
```

Comment: Both answers are exactly what was required. Thank you.

Comment: @pravda23 But you've accepted the least easy one to, in term of code and purpose

Comment: Agreed, but its the one that helps me most to understand now.

Comment: Only trouble is if there's a user called 'user21' or something. In that case, it will read the string 'user2' and change user21 to user41 instead of skipping it.

Answer (score 2):

Read, modify, write back

```
with open("test.txt") as fic:
    content = fic.read()

content = content.replace("user2", "user4")

with open("test.txt", "w") as fic:
    fic.write(content)
```

Using `pathlib.Path`

```
from pathlib import Path
file = Path("test.txt")
file.write_text(file.read_text().replace("user2", "user4"))
```